# Actionscript: Strange alert window "Script is causing..."

Tags: actionscript

A script in this movie is causing Adobe Flash Player 10 to run slowly. etc...

Getting this alert window.

Is it possible to avoid this somehow?

Maybe somewhere there is a limit for operations per second? Maybe i should create a queue with proper interval inside AS3?

Why is this message appearing? **Depending on what exact factors?**

Thanks ;)

**Update**

Hmm it seems it's memory leak somewhere, i think it's because of it.
Garbage collector sucks. :D

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector in Flash is a very tricky beast.  The key is in carefully cleaning up all references to an object, including any event listeners and the object contents.  I only really see this error when dealing with particle systems, where the particles aren't being disposed properly.

This error can also appear in the IDE, caused by 3rd party extensions, so test your swf in a browser to make sure it's your fault!

Comment: There actually was a leak, because of debug logging. Just turned it off and recompiled. Anyway getting message after doing a lot of operations. CPU is not used and no memory leaks. wtf O_o

Comment: Maybe there is somewhere some buffer which gets overflowed?

Comment: Nope, i have rechecked everything.

Comment: Like divillysausages said, doing heavy work like pixel comparisons on a large bitmap can cause too many operations in a frame.  If you can identify the operations that are causing the error you can separate them out using the enterFrame event.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a garbage collector issue. Garbage collection will, at most, pause your SWF for a small time. Either you're performing an action that's taking a looooong time (in the line of pixel operations on an enormous image or something, or heavy operations in a loop), or you've entered into an infinite loop.

Can you give more info on what the SWF is and what it's doing?

Comment: I'm using netGroup and sending data on keyPress via netGroup method sendToNearrest. When game data is received, i'm routing it further if required or passing to javascript via ExternalInterface.

Comment: If I understand this: so in one SWF, you receive a key press, which sends it on to the nearest other SWF in the group. If you receive a message, from another SWF, then you either route it further or pass to JS? What happens if there's only one SWF in the group - do you keep routing it (continuously), or are you blocking for a response that's not coming? If you receive a message and you need to route it further, how do you know when to stop it?

Comment: There is a boolean if(info.fromLocal == true) , then message is for us. Otherwise forward it further.

Comment: can you try disabling the forwarding to see if that's the problem?